# use Jquery .load() with a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, load

I'm sure I'm doing alot wrong here, but specifically I'm trying to pull some info from a form and combine it into a url I can then .load():

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    origin = $('#origin').val();
    destination = $('#destination').val();
    weekDay = $('#weekday').val();
    fullSchedule = origin+'_'+destination+'_'+weekDay+'.html';

    $("#scheduleform :submit").click(function() {           
        $('#schedule').load(fullSchedule);          
        alert( fullSchedule );  
    });
});
```

I can alert the full URL but I can't seem to get it to load in the div (with the id of schedule).

I am basically hobbling together what little jquery I know to make this, so I'm sure it's messy, but I'm just not sure why it would alert properly but not load the div.

Comment: Presumably you've verified that `fullSchedule` returns a valid URL (and is on the **same domain** as the page running the script)? Also, have you tried the `$('#scheduleform').submit(/*...*/)` instead of the `click()`?

Comment: So the HTML in the alert is correct but it is not being loaded in your #schedule div? Are you sure your #schedule is properly set in your HTML (maybe a typo?)

Comment: Yep, on the same domain (in the same directory) and it's a valid url, but I think I'm giving myself a problem by using click() instead of submit. Trying the submit approach now.

Comment: you can strip $(document).ready(function() to $(function() btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Firebug, can you verify that the request is going to the server and that you're getting a response? Also try putting a callback in `load` to see if the load is completing successfully:

```
$('#schedule').load(fullSchedule, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
  alert("Load result: " + responseText + " " + textStatus);
});
```

A few other things:

- Is the URL a valid URL?
- Is it on the same domain?

I noticed one other thing. Is there any reason that you're using `click()` instead of `submit()`? So:

```
$("#scheduleform").submit(function() {
   ...
   return false; //You probably don't want the page to actually submit and reload
});
```

Another way to get around the whole submit business is just to use a standard button that is not a submit button, and bind `click` to it (depending on what you're actually doing of course -- I don't know if you actually want to submit anything).

Comment: Sorry for taking my time on responding to this. Loading the response text helped me find a few errors. Using submit() instead of click(), adding the return false, and fixing a spelling error that I caught with the responseText solved my problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, *next* time I'm gonna **answer** instead of **comment** =) +1

Comment: Haha :p been in your situation before... where I went "Wow should have answered instead of commented" :)

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the form does not get submitted and so reloaded ? you need to stop the default action with [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("#scheduleform :submit").click(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();        
    $('#schedule').load(fullSchedule);
});
```